# How to preload images for faster transition

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript to change the image when the radio button is clicked. When you first load the page there is a delay after each radio button is clicked and then afterwards it runs smoothly. I am guessing this is from it not loading the image until the radio is clicked and I was wondering if there is a way to do this. The javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var switchingImage;
var productid;

function changeImage()
  {
    switchingImage.src = this.value;
    productId.value = this.alt;
  }


window.onload = function() {
var radios = document.getElementById('imageSwitcher').getElementsByTagName('input');
var products = document.getElementById('imageSwitcher').getElementsByTagName('alt');

switchingImage = document.getElementById('imageToSwitch');
productId = document.getElementById('productToSwitch');

for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++)
{
    radios[i].onclick = changeImage;
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936778/jquery-preload-an-image-on-request-with-a-callback-function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preload an image:

```
new Image().src = "path/to/file/image.png";
```

The image will be downloaded and stored in cache for use.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just make an array of images and then reference them later.  The line of code `switchingImage.src = this.value;` would instead reference the array.  When placing the preloaded images into the array, make sure to use the `new` keyword. For example:

```
var preLoad = new Array();
var firstImage = new Image();
firstImage.src = "someLocation/thisImage.jpg";
preLoad.push(firstImage);
```

Doing this for all your images, and then referencing the array `preLoad[imageNumber].src` for use in `switchingImage.src` is how the preloaded images would be collected.